# xlwings set value as string with equal sign (=) not formula

Tags: python, converters, xlwings

I'm trying to paste some string with equal to the cell using `xlwings`.

But I don't want to paste it as a formula.
For example,

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
sh = wb.sheets[0]
sh.range("A1:A10").value = "===hello world!==="
```

gives nothing but it just stopped.

In the `xlwings` [converters and options](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html), I couldn't find any clue to solve this problem.

So how can I set cell value as a string with equal sign inside?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

By adding `'` in front of the string `"===hello world!==="`, I can solve the problem:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
sh = wb.sheets[0]
sh.range("A1:A10").value = "'===hello world!==="
```

Also, I can get the string from the cell.

```py
print(sh.range("A1:A10").value)
```

Output:

```
['===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===', '===hello===']
```